# overload and override which happens when : compile or runtime

Tags: oop

Overload and Override: which one happens at compile time and which one at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overload -> Compile time
Override -> Runtime

Comment: Its ok..we are here for solving each others problem..if your problem is solved then please make this question answered.

Comment: This is not completely true..It depends on the language. Also, override could be compile-time, too - when the overridden function is not virtual, the compiler's choice depends on the type of the calling object.

Comment: @Kiril: If the base class function isn't virtual, I don't think it really counts as "overriding". The exact terminology would depend on the language, but it would normally be something like shadowing or hiding.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on which language you're using, and *how* you're using it.

For example, in Java the overload resolution is *always* performed at compile-time, with override resolution is performed at execution time.

In C# that's still *normally* true - but if you're using C# 4's dynamic typing feature, overload resolution is performed at execution time too:

```
static void Foo(int y) {}
static void Foo(string y) {}

...
dynamic x = 10;
Foo(x); // Calls Foo(int)
x = "hello";
Foo(x); // Calls Foo(string)
```

There are plenty of other languages which behave dynamically too. So you really need to learn the behaviour of the language you're using at the time.